# Animate the elements (progress bars) scrolling down effect on prepend (new Progress bars) in container div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am adding the progress bar dynamically for running multiple parallel processes using jquery prepend under Div container. It's working fine. but, I want to keep 5 progress bar at a time will display. after that looks like replacing the first element.

I want to animate in such a way, the Existing element moves down effect and adding a new element on top.

I have tried to append `slideDown('slow')` and many other jquery method but doesn't work for me.

```
$ProgressBarContainer.prepend($row).slideDown('slow');
```

Here, `$ProgressBarContainer` is a container who holds all progress bars. 
$row is the progress bar element prepending to container.

I want to animate the adding(prepending) process with a move down or scrolling down another siblings' elements.